# online tool to check equations validity

Tags: integration

I am a programmer in computer graphics. Recently I have been dealing with equations from a paper which I am not comfortable with. To use these equations in an efficient way, they need to be a bit refactored. An example:

$$\int_a^b{\beta_r^ep_r(s)ds + \beta_m^ep_m(s)ds}$$

where $\beta_r^e$ and $\beta_m^e$ are constants, can be refactored to avoid uncessessary multiplications:

$$\beta_r^e\int_a^b{p_r(s)ds}+\beta_m^e\int_a^b{p_m(s)ds}$$

I am sure someone comfortable with maths can easily tell if this is true or not, but my math skills only allows me to tell "I think this is correct". This kind of refactoring is very error prone and can give me headaches while debugging if this is incorrect because I have no ideas if the rules I am using are correct.

I am looking for some tool/website that can check equality between the two equations. Does it exists?

Comment: [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to compare two equations? Like f(x)=ax+bx and f(x)=x( a + b ).

Comment: Sorry for the hasty reply, let me say first that you're right with your equations, if $c$ is a constant, then $\int {\rm d}x\;  c f(x) =c \int {\rm d}x\;   f(x)$. As for your second question, just type in `x(a + b) == a x + b x`. The result should be `True`

Comment: No problem. I got it working on wolfram, thanks!